# detect DNS redirect and referrer on backend using PHP

Tags: php, redirect, dns

is it possible - via PHP on the backend - to detect if a webpage request has been redirected via DNS and what the location / address  of the referring server is?

Comment: You can try the [`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). It won't tell you if it was a DNS redirect or click from a link or anything like that. As far as I know, you can't get that info, unless they pass it along in a header or something. It's also easy to manipulate that header and it isn't always set. (some routers removes that header for privacy reasons).

Comment: `REMOTE_HOST` will contain a hostname if the site was accessed via a hostname or an IP address if it was accessed via an IP address. That's probably all the information you can get as DNS is at a lower layer than HTTP.